# How to spin the wheel once in duration of 24 hours with flutter?

Tags: animation, flutter, dart

I have a wheel and want to spin once in the duration of 24 hours.
I used `flutter_spinning_wheel` plugin, but not able to understand of it's argument like `initialSpinAngle:` , `spinResistance:` , `canInteractWhileSpinning:` , `onUpdate:` & `onEnd:`

```
 Container(
   child: ableTospin
   ? SpinningWheel(  // Spinning wheel
       Image.asset('assets/wheel.png', fit: BoxFit.cover,),
       height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.3,
       width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.3,
       initialSpinAngle: _generateRandomAngle(),
       spinResistance: 0.8,
       canInteractWhileSpinning: true,
       dividers: 8,
       onUpdate: _dividerController.add,
       onEnd: _dividerController.add,
       // shouldStartOrStop: ,
     )
   : Container(  //non spinning wheel
      height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.3,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.3,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
       color: Colors.blue,
       image: DecorationImage(
         image: AssetImage('assets/wheel.png', ),
         fit: BoxFit.contain,
       ),
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(130.0)),
      ),

    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specification of package that you are using here but have done similar task like this:

```
Transform.rotate(
      angle: _a,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
           shape: BoxShape.circle,
         ),      
       ),
 ),
```

The you need to create some periodic to set the _a (angle):

```
const oneSec = const Duration(minute: 1);
Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer t) => {
    setState((){
        _a = calcAngle();
    });
});
```

Next is to implement `calcAngle()`:

```
double calcAngle() {
    return _a + (2 * pi) / 60; moving / minute
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 2))..repeat();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _controller,
          builder: (_, child) {
            return Transform.rotate(
              angle: _controller.value * 2 * pi,
              child: child,
            );
          },
          child: FlutterLogo(size: 200),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work what the op is asking the rotation has to be done after every fixed interval.